# iPhone: Unable to NSSortDescriptor on to-many relationship. How to sort?

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I am using a NSFetchRequest which I am sorting via **NSSortDescriptor**.

This work perfectly for all the attributes of the entity being fetched.

There is only one problem (ain't there always?) within that entity I have a relationship to another entity and I would like to sort this one too. But it's giving me the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

Here is my core data setup:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityMonth = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Month" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityMonth];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorItem = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"item.nr" ascending:YES]; //THIS ONE CAUSES THE ERROR!
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorMonth = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"month" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorYear = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"year" ascending:YES];


    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorYear, sortDescriptorMonth, sortDescriptorItem, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.stages = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort on `item.nr` because a `Month` object is related to many `Item` objects, so there are multiple values of `item.nr` for each `Month` object.

Comment: Then how should I approach this if I want to sort all items based on there nr attribute?

Comment: @iJar: Your fetch request returns `Month` objects, not `Item` objects, therefore I do not yet understand what you want exactly.

Comment: This data is displayed in a table view. The month.name is displayed as the section title and the items are rows under each section. The month.year and month.month sorts the sections. Now I am looking for a way to sort the rows based on item.id. Hope this clears up my intention.

Comment: @iJar: Do you use a fetched results controller?

Comment: Nope I am not at the moment. Could this help out?

Comment: @iJar: A FRC has options to group a table view into sections and to sort the items within each sections, that would help. In your particular case it is a bit complicated, because you sort the sections by 2 properties instead of a single property. This is possible with a FRC but, as I said, a bit more complicated. - Alternatively, you could just fetch the `Month` objects (sorted by year and month) and then, for each month, sort the `month.items` array.

Comment: How would I do that to sort them on month.items. I have looked into that as well and read many articles on it but none fit my particular case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19802/discussion-between-martin-r-and-ijar)